# Is there a way to pass the entire exception object to an error handling page in a c# webform

Tags: c#, exception, logging, error-handling, webforms

Seems like I should be able to pass the entire exception object over to another page. In this case I am creating a custom error handling page. I have searched everywhere but I am not finding what I am needing. I'd really like to be able to dissect the error over on my Oops page where I can log the error as well as display the friendly message to my users so they can print the screen and bring it to the apps development team. As an example I'd like to peruse through the frames of the trace

```
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
        var allframes = stackTrace.GetFrames().ToList();
        foreach(var frame in allframes)
        {
            var filename = frame.GetFileName();
            var linenumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
            var method = frame.GetMethod();
            var MethodName = method.Name;
            var Classname = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();
        }
```

So I tried the obvious.

Using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Oops.aspx/Error=?{0}",ex));`

Which generates a newline error.

Using HttpUtility.UrlEncode can't convert the object to a string

Converting to a string looses a pile of data as I see it.

What I have reduced to so far is a shorthand passing of string data that is crippled compared to what I could get if I could get the entire exception object.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Oops.aspx?Error={0}&StackTrace={1}&InnerException={2}&Data={3}&Source={4}&TargetSite={5}&Hresult={6}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException, ex.Data, ex.Source, ex.TargetSite, ex.HResult));
```

So is this just the way it is? Or did I miss something? Seems like I should be able to pass the entire object to another page but then again...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You really do not want to do this in production. It's an attack vector. If users have errors, you need to replicate it on your development system. There you can blurt out all information you want and need to your logs or on screen.

Comment: I am sorry, yes indeed, the information that is importance to the attack vector sector is not displayed except to those of administrator level privilege's. A generic error message is displayed to the general and casual user. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Ok. That out of the way: how would you redirect with,  let's say some result object of a query, that needs to be displayed in a normal page? In the end, that exception is an object. And you want to display its properties.

Comment: Ok how about answer my question and I will handle and worry about special cases along the way. Sheesh.

Comment: Place the error object into session, and then in the target page, grab that object. In other words, I don't think passing as a query parameter in the URL makes much sense. However, in most cases, I redirect users to a main page or project page, and I email the error information to the dev team anyway. In other words, having some error page don't help a lot, since it can often be VERY difficult to re-produce the error of the user anyway. So, add a global error trap, and use that to email, and then redirect uses back to their home page or project page or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for viewing and reviewing my question and providing insight to my query.

I opted for a different route,

Instead of grabbing the exception and directing to the Oops page, I am now directing to the ExceptionUtility.LogException method to log and extract all the details I want then direct over to the Oops page to display a friendly error message.

Thanks everyone!